# What TV show has had the most actors appear on any of the Star Trek movies and/or TV series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-enterprise, actors

Watching an episode of Frasier followed by watching the TNG episode [Cause and Effect](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwivptCRkdXTAhWp7YMKHTlXCqAQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCause_and_Effect_(Star_Trek%3A_The_Next_Generation)&usg=AFQjCNGtcvFVyihQyXRft9avp4Isws-kCw&sig2=GFcK9b-3TuAjczEUHtvlQQ) with Kelsey Grammer as Captain Morgan Bateson got me to thinking.  What TV show has had the most actors appear on any of the Star Trek movies and/or TV series?

To make this a bit easier I would like to only count TV shows in which a recurring starring cast member appears on Star Trek.  E.g. in the sitcom Big Bang theory we have Wil Wheaton, Levar Burton, Brent Spiner & Leonard Nimoy (voice only) all in Star Trek. However only Wil Wheaton would be considered a regular starring role with 13 appearances and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wil_Wheaton) specifically referring to it as a recurring role.  Otherwise shows which simply have the same guest star popping between that show (e.g. 1 or 2 episodes) and Star Trek is not what I am seeking.

From the following [site](http://www.warpedfactor.com/2014/11/25-famous-people-who-guest-starred-on.html) which lists famous celebrities whom have appeared on Star Trek I can see at least two shows that have three actors each and two more with two.

1. Cheers   : The aforementioned Kelsey Grammer, Bebe Neuwirth as the nurse in TNG First Contact and Kirstie Alley as Lt. Saavik in TWOK.
2. Frasier      : Again the aforementioned Kelsey Grammer, Bebe Neuwirth as the nurse in TNG First Contact and Saul Rubinek in TNG The Most Toys.
3. Lost     : Daniel Dae Kim as Corporal Chang in Enterprise (Hatchery, Extinction & Th Xindi) and Astronaut Gotana-Retz in Voyager Blink of an Eye & Terry O'Quinn as Admiral Eric Pressman in TNG The Pegasus
4. Quantum Leap : Scott Bakula as Captain Archer in Enterprise and Dean Stockwell in Colonel Grat in Enterprise Detained

Thanks.

Comment: Futurama where a lot of the cast of TNG lent their voice?

Comment: Boston Legal needs to have some consideration; it had Kirk, Odo, even Quark at one point.

Comment: @NKCampell.  As the Futurama appearance was a one time guest appearance, I would not consider that to be recurring.

Comment: @Tim.  A solid mention with the three characters you noted. Though as Armin Shimerman only appeared in 7 episodes of the series, I would consider it slightly weaker than the Frasier and Cheers episodes with three characters each that occurred in at least 13 episodes each.

Comment: @beichst - if it's appearances that count, Shatner appeared in 101 episodes, and René Auberjonois was in 71 episodes.  So in terms of total episodes, that's probably the top.  If you're going by number of actors though, it's harder to tell.  They had the entire cast of TNG in one episode of Family Guy.

Comment: Trivially, the various Star Trek series themselves (the winner being the one with the largest cast of regular and recurring characters, my guess would be DS9).  But I suppose that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Tim. In this case it is a minimum number of episodes by individual. That is for a character to count he/she must have enough episodes on the candidate show to be considered either a listed regular cast member or a recurring member. Generally that is going to be at least 13 episodes or what used to be considered a half season.  Actually any more 13 episodes is becoming a full season for many shows.

Comment: How has no one mentioned Gargoyles? Jonathan Frakes, Mirina Sirtis, Michael Dorn, Kate Mulgrew, Brent Spiner, all in recurring or starring roles. There were certainly other ST regulars in a few guest roles too, from TNG, DS9, and even TOS.

Comment: Since this question is on-hold right now, would it make sense on the Movies and TV stack?

Comment: @Ellesedil This question is on-topic and is now in the re-open votes queue.

Comment: @RDFozz.  Thank you for the correction. Have updated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## The Young and the Restless (28)

*Based on at least 13 appearances in the show and a credited appearance for Star Trek (series only) in the IMDB data (up to 2017-04-28)*

- Aaron Lustig [VOY: Doctor]
- Albie Selznick [TNG: Juggler / VOY: Tak Tak / Tash]
- Alicia Coppola [VOY: Lt. Stadi]
- Amy O'Neill [TNG: Annette]
- Clyde Kusatsu [TNG: Admiral Nakamura]
- Corbin Bernsen [TNG: Q2]
- Eric Steinberg [VOY: Ankari]
- James Wellington [DS9: Al]
- Jessica Collins [VOY: Linnis Paris]
- Julianna McCarthy [DS9: Mila]
- Karen Hensel [DS9: Deela / TNG: Admiral Brackett]
- Keone Young [DS9: Buck Bokai]
- Kevin McCorkle [VOY: Alien Captain]
- Leigh McCloskey [DS9: Joran Belar / VOY: Tieran]
- Leslie Bevis [DS9: Rionoj / Freighter Captain]
- Lise Simms [VOY: Annorax's Wife]
- Lorna Raver [VOY: Q-Judge]
- Michael Cavanaugh [TNG: Cpt. Robert DeSoto]
- Michael Fairman [DS9: Vendor]
- Mike Starr [DS9: Tony Cicci]
- Phil Morris [DS9: Remata'Klan / Thopok / VOY: Lt. John Kelly]
- Ray Wise [VOY: Arturis / TNG: Liko]
- Sandra Nelson [DS9: Tavana / VOY: Marayna]
- Sherman Augustus [VOY: Hij'Qa]
- Stephanie Erb [TNG: Liva]
- Stephen Gregory [TNG: Jake Kurland]
- Terry Lester [VOY: Haron]
- Tony Todd [TNG: Kurn / Korban / DS9: Adult Jake Sisko / VOY: Alpha Hirogen]

Answer (score 3):

Disney's [Gargoyles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargoyles_(TV_series)) had a fairly large crossover group. It was made at the height of TNG and, because of Jonathan Frakes (who played Riker, and who directed several episodes of DS9 and Voyager) it frequently featured other actors from those series

- Jonathan Frakes (TNG, William Riker) - David Xanatos
- Mirana Sirtis (TNG, Deanna Troi) - Demona

These characters were recurring, but not central

- Kate Mulgrew (Voyager, Katherine Janeway) - Anastasia Renard (Xanatos' eventual mother-in-law)
- Brent Spiner (TNG, Data) - Puck
- Michael Dorn (TNG & DS9, Worf) - Coldstone

The rest were guest characters

- Nichelle Nichols (TOS, Uhura) - Diana Maza
- Levar Burton (TNG, Geordi LaForge) - Anansi
- Colm Meaney (TNG & DS9 - Chief O'Brien) - Mr. Dugan
- Avery Brooks (DS9 - Benjamin Sisko) - Nokkar

Comment: Other frequent characters in Gargoyles that had a credit in ST are: John Rhys-Davies [Voy: Leonardo da Vinci], Frank Welker as [VOY: Alien Creature], Salli Richardson-Whitfield [DS9: Fenna/Nidell]

Answer (score 1):

Babylon 5 had

- Walter Koenig (Chekov)
- Andreas Katsulas (Tomalak)
- Bill Mumy (Kellin on DS9 episode *The Siege of AR-558*)
- Patricia Tallman (security officer on TNG episode *Power Play* as well as stunts if that counts) -

**Edit** Adding from comments below

- Tracy Scoggins (a Cardassian in DS9 *Destiny*)

I'm guessing there are others

I know Majel Barret/Roddenberry (Number One, Ship's Computer, Lwaxana Troi) was on B5 as a Centauri Prophet, but that was a guest appearance so I suppose it doesn't count.

Comment: Tracy Scoggins (from B5 Season 5) was also a Cardassian in DS9 (Destiny), also one of the three Klingon Dahar masters from DS9 was a technomage in B5.

Comment: @colmde. Thank you for the submission. It looks like 4 is the new number to beat.  Nicely done.    Agreed on Majel Barrett as a guest appearance only. Thanks.

Comment: Make that 5 with Tracy Scoggins.